# Rendering models from an ember-data store, using a http-mock server and RESTAdapter fails

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having some issued with hooking up ember-data to a http-mock using a simple model. I want to load an API containing properties, and render them as a list on a page.

When navigating to the `/properties/` route described below, this is the error being thrown:

```
Error: Not Found
    at ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$Adapter.extend.ajaxError (rest-adapter.js:714)
    at ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$Adapter.extend.ajax.Ember.RSVP.Promise.hash.error (rest-adapter.js:789)
    at jQuery.Callbacks.fire (jquery.js:3143)
    at Object.jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:3255)
    at done (jquery.js:9311)
    at XMLHttpRequest.jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback (jquery.js:9713)
```

and the template doesn't render.

Here's what I've done:

1. Added a `property` model:

> ```
> import DS from 'ember-data';
>
> export default DS.Model.extend({
>     title: DS.attr('string'),
>     date_added:  DS.attr('date')
> });
> ```

2. Added a 'routes/properties.js' that looks like this:

> ```
> import Ember from 'ember';
>
> export default Ember.Route.extend({
>   model: function() {
>     return this.store.find('property');
>   }
> });
> ```

3. Added an application adapter in `app.js`:

> ```
> App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
>   namespace: 'api',
>   host: 'http://localhost:4200/'
> });
> ```

4. Used a generator, `ember g http-mock property` to generate a mock server. Here is a relevant snippet from my `server/mocks/property.js`:

> ```
> propertyRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
>   res.send({
>     'property': [{
>       id: 1,
>       title: "Apartament cu 4 camere ultracentral doar pentru pretențioși"
>     },(...)]
>   });
> });
> ```

Please note that `curl -H "ContentType:application/json" http://localhost:4200/api/property/` works like a charm.

5. I have a route, `this.route("properties", { path: '/properties'});` that renders `templates/properties.hbs`, and in that template I attempt to display all properties, as follows:

> ```
> {{#each property as |p|}}
>   <div class="property">
>     {{p.title}}
>   </div>
> {{/each}}
> ```

6. If, at `2.`, I replace `return this.store.find('property');` with `return [1,2,3]`, it no longer breaks, and I'm able to iterate that collection. What I found, then, is that `this.store.find` is what is causing the problem.

Any idea on how to handle this? Do you need any other setup/code snippets?

The versions for ember/ember-data are *"ember": "1.11.1", "ember-data": ">= 1.0.0-beta.16.1",*

Comment: Open dev tools in your browser and go to the network tab, what are the properties of the request generated?

Comment: Give a try to https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage

Comment: Ember-data automatically uses an inflector for pluralization. Your node mock should respond to /properties, not /property

Comment: @givanse There are 2 requests that 404 with `Cannot GET /properties`. Since I configured the RESTAdapter to use `/api/` to namespace requests, I don't understand why it isn't looking for `/api/properties`.

Comment: @BriscBogdan Good point, I changes it so the mock server respons to /api/properties/, still no dice.

Answer (score 2):

As I suspected, the REST adapter I was configuring was ignored by the configuration. I solved the problem by declaring an adapter and passing it as an argument when creating the `App` object.

> ```
> var customRESTAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
>   namespace: 'api',
>   host: 'http://localhost:4200'
> });
>
> App = Ember.Application.extend({
>   modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
>   podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
>   Resolver: Resolver,
>   ApplicationAdapter: customRESTAdapter,
> });
> ```

Word of caution, the previous code at `3.` was downright *not working*, even though it's referenced in at least 3 places in the official documentation. Since I'm just starting to dip into Ember, this was kind of a disappointment, I'm not sure how up-to-date the docs are, but yeah be wary.

This, alongside @BriscBogdan's mention of rember-data's automatic inflexion solved my issue.

Comment: The ember-cli documentation is better than the emberjs documentation right now. I kept the adapter in the typical place and just imported it but I'm still getting 404s. Thanks for posting this question. It's been very helpful. Edit: if you look at http://www.ember-cli.com/#testing they show how to setup mocks. I think your issue is that your still using the global namespace `APP` when ember-cli expects you to import objects.

Comment: Yeah, ember-cli is really well documented, and I like using it to generate code before I write anything myself, really lets you organize the app better.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that you're trying to use the global namespace `APP` rather than exporting a module when you define your adapter. Ember expects the adapter for `properties` to be defined in `app/adapters/property.coffee`. It should look something like:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api',
  host: 'http://localhost:4200'
});
```

Then, remove the `ApplicationAdapter` line from your `app.js`:

```
App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
  podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
  Resolver: Resolver
});
```

Thanks for posting this question. I was stuck at the same point and it really helped to see what you had done.

Comment: Actually yeah good point, it's much cleaner to use a module to do this, rather than clog up the App namespace. I'll give it a go later on, and mark your answer as correct if I get it working.